# State of static variable in DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll

**Scenario:**

My Application bind a **library  X** which has static class. I initialize it in my process.
After some time when I load a dll which also use same **library X**.

I see content of **static variable in dll is not initialized**. Where **I already initialized it in process** before loading DLL.

I added initialization code in DLL main , and its working now.

**Question :** I need to understand this behavior / case.

Comment: A debugger will show you what's happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

library x is clearly linked as a static library against both the exe, and the dll :- in order to get the behavior you want, library X itself needs to be built as a shared library. So then "my application.exe" and "a.dll" would both use "libraryx.dll" as a result there would only by one instance of the static value.

Comment: Agree, I ran into this once when writing a logging lib in which I had a static logger (singleton).